# How to make k-means distributed?

Tags: python, apache-hadoop, k-means, map-reduce, distributed

After setting up a [2-noded Hadoop cluster](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/hadoop-cluster-with-pc-and-virtualbox/), understanding [Hadoop and Python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) and based on this naive [implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80050/k-means-clustering-algorithm-in-python), I ended up with this code:

```
def kmeans(data, k, c=None):
    if c is not None:
        centroids = c
    else:
        centroids = []
        centroids = randomize_centroids(data, centroids, k)

    old_centroids = [[] for i in range(k)] 

    iterations = 0
    while not (has_converged(centroids, old_centroids, iterations)):
        iterations += 1

        clusters = [[] for i in range(k)]

        # assign data points to clusters
        clusters = euclidean_dist(data, centroids, clusters)

        # recalculate centroids
        index = 0
        for cluster in clusters:
            old_centroids[index] = centroids[index]
            centroids[index] = np.mean(cluster, axis=0).tolist()
            index += 1


    print("The total number of data instances is: " + str(len(data)))
```

I have tested it for serial execution and it is OK. How to make it distributed in Hadoop? In other words, what should go to the reducer and what to the mapper?

*Please* note that *if* possible, I would like to follow the tutorial's style, since it's something I have understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are trying to do this as a learning exercise, just use Spark which has ML libraries made for distributed computing. See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html)

Comment: Bob sorry, I want to learn, not just call a function, I shall update my question, but you deserve an upvote for throwing that info for future use! ;)